# Use of the word "read"

Tags: word-usage

I'm writting a short-story and I'm describing a character who is sitting down and reading a book.

> (...) grabbing a small book lying on the floor beside her. The title
>   read *Dark Flame* (...)

Is it correct to say "The title read *Dark Flame*" meaning "The title of the book is *Dark Flame*"? Because it kinda sounds a little strange, but that's probably because I'm not a native speaker.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Read" is two different words -- one pronounced "reed" and one pronounced "red".  (I'll leave it to someone else to edit in the IPA if they wish.)  The first means to scan text and interpret it as language.  The second is the past tense of the first.

But, in addition, the  verb "read" (either version) can be used in a context where the subject is not the person doing the scanning and interpreting, but rather is the piece of text (or the object bearing it), and the object is the contents of that piece of text.

In the sentence you quote, "The title" is the subject, "read" (the "red" past tense version) is the verb, and "Dark Flame" is the object.